# Receiving and update image through websocket implemented with node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm not a programmer...
I can create a websocket aplication in node.js, that can send an image to borwser, but I will have few images, that changed sometimes.
Ex.
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
image4.jpg
and I need to keep updated this images in browser.

My app now work only with one image, without update.
The full project is hear: https://github.com/akoscomp/imgstream
I publish the image with this code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, buf){
    //it's impossible to ebed binary data
    socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
    console.log('image file is initialized: ' + __dirname + '/image.jpg');
});});
```

And I can check the file update, but I can't automate the update on browser:

```
   var watch = require('node-watch');
watch('image.jpg', function(evt, filename) {
  console.log(filename, ' changed.');
});
```

Please help me to automate the image update in borwser. After that I probably can apply the code for many images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send image once it is change using the following code.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

  // Diconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected %s sockets connected', connections.length);
  });

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, buf) {
    //it's impossible to ebed binary data
    socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
    console.log('image file is initialized: ' + __dirname + '/image.jpg');
  });
});


var watch = require('node-watch');

watch('image.jpg', function(evt, filename) {
  if (evt === 'update') {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, buf) {
      for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        //it's impossible to ebed binary data
        connections[i].emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
        console.log('image file is initialized: ' + __dirname + '/image.jpg');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

You can check the complete project at https://github.com/yanalavishnu/imgstream

Comment: I can write a code for multiple files, now I can display a custom number of images.